# JSX Not rendering

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, jsx

I'm working through an online course on React and Meteor. Whenever I hit the submit button it registers the new player in the database, but it doesn't actually show p on the client side. I get the following in the console:

> Exception from Tracker recompute function:
>   Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {playerName}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons."

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
 import {Tracker} from 'meteor/tracker';

 import {Players} from './../imports/api/players.js';

 const renderPlayers = (playersList) => {

    return playersList.map( (player) =>{
        return <p key={player._id}>{player.name} has {player.score} points!</p>;
    });
 };

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    let playerName = e.target.playerName.value;

    e.preventDefault();

    if (playerName) {

    e.target.playerName.value = '';

    Players.insert({
    name: playerName,
    score: 0
    });
   }
 };
 Meteor.startup( () => {

    Tracker.autorun( () => {
        let players = Players.find().fetch();
        let title = 'Score Keeper';
        let name = 'Bill';
        let jsx = (
            <div>
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <p>Hello {name}!</p>
                <p>Second p</p>
                {renderPlayers(players)}
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" name="playerName" placeholder="Player Name"/>
                    <button>Add Player</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            );
        ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('app'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive that this line:
`let players = Players.find().fetch();`  is not returning an array as you expected.
I'm guessing `.fetch` is returning an object (maybe with `.data` in it?) and that's why you are getting this error.
Try logging the `players` object after `.fetch` finished and see what's inside this object.

Comment: it gives me two array's of objects. The first being the 4 that do in fact show up in the browser as text and the other one contains the 29 objects that are in the database.

Comment: in this line `Players.insert({...` are you trying to insert an object to the imported object `Players`? you know, imported objects are like a `const`

Comment: It's working now...I cleared the documents in the DB and it worked just fine. Weird